# Prove 1/2 is a Lebesgue number of this cover.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the topological space $(X,{\tau_x})$ where X = $(-{\infty}, 2)$ and ${\tau_x}$ is the subspace topology that X inherits from the standard topology of the space of real numbers. Let $(C_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the family of subsets of X given by $C_n = (-n, 2-1/n)$ and $A$ be the union of {$C_n$} with $(1,2)$

Show that A has Lebesgue number 1/2

This is done using the following definition:
Denote by $B(x;\delta)$ the open ball around x with radius $\delta.$
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A= (U_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}$be an open cover of $X$. For $\epsilon>0, A$ has Lebesgue number $\epsilon$ if and only if:

$\forall x \in X$   $\exists \beta \in I: B(x;\delta) \subset U_\beta$

I've been trying to solve this problem for quite some time now. So far my method has been breaking down the problem into open intervals and trying to prove that any value $x$ in these intervals is a subset of a specific element of A for all $\delta \in (0,1/2)$, but I don't see how this is posisble for say, $\delta = 0.2$ and x = $1.9$.

I'm rather stuck, any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: There are different definitions of a Lebesgue number. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3023051. Which do you use? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks for the heads up, edited it to include the definition I used. Apologies, was not aware of any other definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$, let $r=\frac{d}{2}$, let $x\in(-\infty,2-r)$, and let $I=(x-r,x+r)$. Observe that $\operatorname{diam}(I)=d$. If $x+r=2$, then $x-r=2-d>\frac{3}{2}>1$, so $I\subseteq(1,2)$. Suppose now that $x+r<2$. Then there exists some $N\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x+r<2-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq N$. Furthermore, let $\mathbb{Z}^+\ni n'>r-x$. Setting $n=\max\{N,n'\}$ we get that

$$-n\leq n'<x-r$$

and

$$x+r<2-\frac{1}{n}.$$

In particular it follows that $I\subseteq\left(-n,2-\frac{1}{n}\right)=C_n$. As any subset of $X$ with diameter less than $\frac{1}{2}$ is contained in such an interval, and every such interval is contained in an element of $\{C_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}\cup(1,2)$, it follows that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a Lebesgue number of the cover.